# When attaching PNG to MFMailComposer, images auto-rotate to landscape swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, png, mfmailcomposer

I am making a simple camera app where a user takes an image and then emails it. I have one problem: once the user takes an image (which always works), **if it is portrait, the MFMailComposer auto-rotates it to landscape incorrectly, making everything sideways.** How can I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because PNGs do not store orientation information. Attach the photo to the email as a JPG instead and it will be oriented correctly!

Use this code to attach your image instead:

```
let data:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9)! // 0.9 is compression value: 0.0 is most compressed/lowest quality and 1.0 is least compressed/highest quality
mailcomposer.addAttachmentData(data, mimeType: "image/jpg", fileName: "image.jpg")
```

Source + more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34796890/5700898